# Mule API - Process API's

Tags: api, mule

I have a question regarding the API invocations in Mule. If we have 3 layer API's Experience, Process and System API's, is it always mandatory to invoke process API from Experience API or can Experience API invoke System API directly in cases where there is no need for any orchestration. I want to know what does the Mule best practice suggest.

Below are my scenarios:

Scenario 1 which requires Process Layer API:

System API fetch data from various back end systems, process API does the orchestration and create a single response, Experience API invokes this Process API to send the data to the consuming applications.

Scenario 2 which doesn't require Orchestration:
I need to pass the data fetched from 1 System API as is to the client via Experience API, there is no orchestration required.

Can I invoke system API directly from Experience API or do I need to have a pass through Process API for the sake of right architecture design in scenario2?

Answer (score 2):

As part of the MuleSoft best practices you can call System directly from Experience.

For the scenario one, you definitely need a process.
You would have multiple systems which will be called by your process. Your experience calls you process.

For scenario two, it's absolutely fine calling directly from experience and it's actually well design as it wil